# $L^2$ and Schwartz Space

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

It is stated, *Introduction to the theory of Pseudodiffernetial Operators, by Raymond, pg 9, Theorem 16*,  if $S$ is the Schwartz space

> If $\varphi \mapsto U(\varphi)$  is a semilinear form on $ S$ satisfying $|U(\varphi)|\le C||\varphi||_2$, then there exists  a unique $u \in L^2$ such that $U(\varphi) = (u, \varphi)$ for $\varphi\in S$ and one has $||u||_2 \le C$.

I don't see how this is true from their argument:

They said we use Riesz Representation Theorem - but $S \subsetneq L^2$. So is this statement true? If so, how do we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $U$ by Hahn Banach Theorem and then apply Riesz' Theorem.

Comment: Hi Kavi, I believe I have another similar question, which I am fundamentally confused, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183536/l2-and-sobolev-space.