# $L^2$ and Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

In Raymond's book on Pseudodifferential Operator page 18, he says , where $S'$ is the tempered distributions, we define sobolev space of exponent $s$ as

> $u \in S'$ with $\lambda^s \hat{u} \in L^2$. **This is equivalent to** $\hat{u}$ is a function satisfying 
>    $$ ||u||_s^2 =(2 \pi)^{-n} \int (1+|\xi|^2 )^s |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \,d \xi < \infty $$ 
>   $\lambda^s (\xi) = (1+|\xi|^2 )^\frac{s}{2}$.

My concern is if $u \in S'$, then $u:S \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous semi linear norm. How does this guarantee $\hat{u}$ is a "function"?

Let me make this more precise.

---

Let us denote $u \in S'$ by $L_u$ as it is a linear functional.  So $L_u: S \rightarrow \Bbb C$ is a tempered dsitribution. We define $\hat{u}$ by 
$$L_{\hat{u}} (\varphi) = L_{u}(\hat{\varphi}(-x)), \quad \forall \varphi \in S$$

So this is our $\hat{u}:=L_{\hat{u}}$. *This is an element in $S'$*.

So what exactly does it mean to say that $\lambda^s \hat{u} \in L^2$? So I guess we *embed $L^2$ into $S'$* I.e. there exists $\varphi \in L^2$ such that

$$\lambda^s \hat{u} (f) = \int f \bar{\varphi} $$
for all $f \in S$?

Comment: Isn't it just the definition of being in $L^2$?

Comment: $\lambda^s \hat u \in L^2$ implies $\hat u$ is a measurable function (i.e. in both definitions, that $\hat u$ is a function and not just a distribution is part of the assumptions)

Comment: Isn't $\hat{u}$ the Fourier transform of $u$?

Comment: $f \in L^2$[first def.] means $f$ is a measurable function such that squared integral is finite[second def.]. The equivalence is exactly by the definition of the $L^2$ norm, which is why Kavi gave you the answer below. However this is apparently not your problem and I dont know what the problem actually is. You know exactly what function $\lambda^s$ is so in addition for $\lambda^s \hat u\in L^2$ to make sense, $\hat u$ is /assumed/ to be a function. (In particular, if $s\ge 0$, this implies that $u$ is also a function.)

Comment: My problem is $\lambda^s \hat{u}$ does  *not make sense* to be in $L^2$ if we were to assume $u \in S'$. Since by *definition* $\lambda^s \hat{u} \in S'$. So I suppose we identify $L^2$ in $S'$? 

(Ok, I deleted my previous comments, so chat doesn't go to long).

Comment: I would agree with you if $\lambda^s \hat u \in S'$ would imply that $\lambda^s \hat u$ is not in $L^2$? But every locally integrable function is naturally an element of $S'$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm completely confused with this conversation now, are there any good references I may look at?

Comment: OK, I'll attempt to write something up... I would expect Duistermaat and Kolk's book on distributions to have something on sobolev spaces? A more standard reference is (I believe but cant check atm) Rudin's Functional Analysis

Comment: Re: your edit, yes, $L^2 $ forms a subset of the locally integrable functions $L^1_{loc}$,  and for any function $f\in L^1_{loc}$, $f\in S'$ by the identification of $f$ with $\phi \mapsto \int f\phi $

Comment: So the problem is how does the equation make sense... how do you evaluate $\hat{u}$ on an element in $\Bbb R^n$. Or is the deifnition wrong in the first place?

Comment: the assumptions imply that there exists an $L^2$ function $g$ such that $\phi\mapsto \int g\bar \phi$ is equal to the linear functional $\hat u$ in $S'$ (perhaps clearest in $s=0$). The evaluation of the functional $\hat u$ at a point is understood as the evaluation of $g$ at a point, and one abusively writes $g=u$. (this is the above mentioned identification)

Comment: Why is evaluation of $\hat{u}$ at a point equal to evaluation of $g$ at a point?  If as you said a point is a function, shouldn't $\hat{u}(x) = x \int \bar{g} $ being the constant function?

Comment: There does not need to be a reason that answers your 'why'. This is a definition of the notation, so it is simply taken to be true. PS I cannot understand how you got to that, since tempered distirbutions cannot be tested against constant functions, which are not Schwartz. PPS it is for avoiding confusion like yours that I try not to write $u(f)$ for evaluation of a distribution, and instead use something like $(u,f)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be on understanding the assumption $\lambda^s \hat u \in L^2$, since $\hat u$ is only an element of $S'$.

1. Important to keep in mind is the identification of $f\in L^1_{loc}$ with the distribution $T_f\in S'$ defined by $(T_f,\phi) = \int f\bar{\phi}$ for every $\phi\in S$. The map $ T :   L^1_{loc} \to S'$ that sends $f\mapsto T_f$ is a continuous embedding, and one usually abusively writes $f=T_f$, but I'll avoid using it below.
2. On the one hand, as $\lambda^s\in C^\infty$ with polynomial growth of derivatives, $\lambda^s \hat u$ is well-defined as an element of $S'$. On the other hand, the assumption $\lambda^s \hat u\in L^2$ is read as (to be understood as) there exists $f\in L^2$ such that $T_f = \lambda^s \hat u$. [By the above identification $f=\lambda^s\hat u$, we treat $\lambda^s \hat u$ as a function.]
3. This implies that $\hat u$ is $T_g$ for some $g\in L^2$. Indeed, set $g = f/\lambda^s$, a well defined quotient of measurable functions. As $\lambda^s$ is bounded a.e. away from $0$, and $f\in L^1_{loc}$, $g$ is in $L^1_{loc}$. Then
   $$ (\hat u,\phi) =( \hat u,\lambda^s\lambda^{-s} \phi ) = (\lambda^s \hat u,\lambda^{-s} \phi ) = (T_f,\lambda^{-s} \phi)=(T_{f\lambda^{-s}}, \phi) = (T_g,\phi)$$
   so $\hat u = T_g$.

PS for $s\ge 0$, $u$ is also a function, since $\hat u \in L^2$ by $L^\infty-L^1$ Holder's inequality. There are distributions that are not functions in $H^s$ for $s<0$. For instance, the Dirac delta which is in $S'(\mathbb R^d)$, is also in $H^{-d/2-\epsilon}(\mathbb R^d)$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Calvin, and sorry for all the problem.

Comment: @CL. its OK, better to ask than to not understand! also I edited some typos out and added a comment

Comment: do you mind having a look at my most recent question in defining the index of an essentially self adjoint operator?

Comment: Sorry, I regretfully don't know PDO theory... @CL.

Answer (score -1):

It i,s just the  definition of $L^{2}$ norm. Just square $\lambda^{s}\hat {u}$ and integrate. I thing the book defines $L^{2}$ space by taking the reference measure as Lebesgue measure divided by $(2\pi)^{n}$.

Comment: My concern is $\hat{u} $ is a linear functional on $S$. How does the "function" part make sense?

Comment: Hi Kavi, I think I am confused fundamentally by what it means for $\lambda^s \hat{u} \in L^2 $.

Comment: A function $f$ beongs to $L^{2}$ if $|f|^{2}$ is integrable.

Comment: My problem is those are not functions by linear functionals by definition -I updated my post.

Comment: That is the way the Sobolev space is defined. A requirement for a tempered distribution  to be in the Sobolev space is that it is actually a function with the stated integrability property.

Comment: I'm completely lost, $\hat{u}$ is a linear functional on $S$, and now it is also a function defined on $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: $1$ is a natural number, an integer, a rational number, a real number, a complex number, a constant function, a measurable function, and a distribution at the same time.

Comment: Any locally integrable function is identified with the distribution which maps a test function $g$ to the value $\int gh$. With this identification  locally integrable functions are also considered as linear functionals on the space of test functions.

Comment: This is however not precisely the same as the case here. $S$ is not the space of test functions but is the set of Schwartz function. So it only identifies with a subspace of it. Do you believe that the definition maybe incorrect, but intead we wnat $u \in S$? (OR  is it harmless to make this assumption).

Comment: A tempered distribution is a distribution (i.e. a continuous linear function on the space of test functions) which can be extended continuously to the Schwarz space. The extension is unique. Any tempered distribution can be restricted to the space of test functions and, in special cases, this restriction may correspond to an ordinary function. It is precisely with these identifications in mind that distributions are also called **generalized functions**.